# copy multiple columns with same name but different number into new df in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a huge dataframe physioDf and want to copy some of the columns into a different df called smallPysioDf. I know, that I can copy individual columns like this:

```
smallPhysioDf['column_name'] = physioDf['column_name'].values
```

But I now want to copy 30 columns belonging to the same Variable. Each column names starts the same (e.g. "VariableName_") but end with a specific number from 1 to 30. What would be the fastest way to copy all of those columns into smallPhysioDf? I believe I would have to use a for loop but I am not sure how. Very happy for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be quickest to select all columns at once:

```
columns = [f"VariableName_{i}" for i in range(1, 31, 1)]
smallPhysioDf = physioDf[columns].copy()
```

If `smallPhysioDf` already exists you can instead append (if the `VariableName` columns are already in the DataFrame), or merge (if the `VariableName` columns are new).

Comment: Thank you very much! This works fine for the columns 10-30 but not for the first nine since they have leading zeros (sorry that I didn't mention that in my original post). Can you help me out with how to include leading zeros to columns with i<10?

Comment: Yes just use string formatting: `[f"VariableName_{i:02}" for i in range(1, 31, 1)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` to extract the column names:

```
for c in physioDf.filter(regex='^VariableName_').columns:
      smallPhysioDf[c] = physioDf[c]
```

Or you can use f-string:

```
for n in range(1,31):
    col_name = f'VariableName_{n}'
    smallPhysioDf[col_name] = physioDf[col_name]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The latter way works although I need to change it to physioDf[col_name].values to copy the values in the rows aswell. The problem is that VariableName_ with n<10 have leading zeros. Any idea how to include that into the code?

Comment: You don't need to chain it with `.values`. The values are automatically copied.

Comment: When I didn't add .values I got NaNs instead of the values in the cells. I edited my last comment because I also need to include leading zeros in n<10. Any idea? Thank you in advance

Comment: Oh, so `smallPhysioDf` has different indexing than `physioDf`? In which case, yes, you do need `.values` to pass the numpy array.

Comment: Yes, you were right! After I made sure the index of both dfs was the same I didn't need to add .value anymore